# GUI not appearing on second monitor

Tags: nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, gui

I just installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 20.04.1 on my Dell G5 intel gaming laptop.
Any extended monitors display the desktop background, and my mouse cursor, but when i try to drag a window over from my primary display (inbuilt to the laptop and working fine) it simply becomes invisible in parts that pass onto the next screen. I have tried switching from open source drivers to NVIDIA's proprietary ones, and checked every proprietary driver available through Ubuntu's software & updates "additional drivers" dialog, to no avail- the issue persists with any monitor i plug in. the graphics card in the laptop is an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Mobile. I've checked that the resolutions are set accurately, as are the refresh rates, and I have run ubuntu 20.04.1 on this laptop before, and the monitors had no issues then. How can i rectify this issue?

Comment: Are you sure the second monitor display is attached to the side you think it is?  Check with the Settings/Display and attach the screens the way you want.

Comment: the screens are oriented properly- the cursor passes fine, but the window does not (visually) come with, though it is logically there and i can interact with it blindly. all i see is the desktop background.

Answer (score 0):

I did end up getting this working again- through the "software and updates" program on ubuntu, i went to the additional drivers tab and switched to the "nvidia-drver-460" driver, the mistake i was making was failing to reboot and "enroll MOK" for secure boot- i was just continuing to boot.